# SQLite ExecuteReader --> DataTable.Load --> FormatException (DateTime)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlite

I tried to read out a sample Northwind sqlite database but get an error on some tables with a datetime. Is this a problem of the database or of my System.Data.SQLite?
The Exception is somethin like: "the string is not a valid DateTime"

http://system.data.sqlite.org/

Of cource I can read out the data by myself with the correct converting of datetime but this is not as performant as reading it out via a simple dt.Load()

```
        SQLiteCommand dbCommand = myConnector.CreateCommand();
        dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename;

        SQLiteDataReader executeReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(executeReader); // <-- FormatException
```

> "   bei System.DateTimeParse.ParseExactMultiple(String s, String[]
>   formats, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)\r\n   bei
>   System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String[] formats, IFormatProvider
>   provider, DateTimeStyles style)\r\n   bei
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConvert.ToDateTime(String dateText,
>   SQLiteDateFormats format, DateTimeKind kind) in
>   c:\dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.SQLite\SQLiteConvert.cs:Zeile
>   322."

I need a good help to improve the current code.

Comment: Just throwing out an idea... usually this type of thing is hidden somewhere (in a trigger perhaps)... Maybe the logging mechanisms have incorrectly formated dates? I bet the problem is not with converting your query to a DataTable, but something else is happening.

Comment: please can you tell me the format of the offending DateTime column in the table

Comment: the sample database is this: http://download.vive.net/Northwind.zip and the table is 'ORDERS'. according to SQLite Database Browser the offending columns are from type 'timestamp'

Comment: +1 for question, I never found the answer on google. Just reading the documentation and thinking about it I solved this issue.

Comment: Did you solve the issue with my answer? If you resolve it, please accept it. If not, please comment

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yep, I faced the same problem, and I've found a solution.

First of all you need to know why it happens.

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

**

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:

**

```
TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
```

> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

For more date/time functions you can see this page:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

***SOLUTION:***

Is just use a datetime function to convert your field into a valid .NET datatable format. You can use anyone from the above link, in my case I choose:

```
SELECT datetime(field) as field FROM table
```

***TIP 1***
If your query is on a view, and you can't touch your db, create a different view or something like, you are in a little trouble because the problem is on the db side as I explain before. So the first solution is replace the column of a datatable before load (a little dirty work). Or you can use a Unix stamp on a text field, or any desired timestamp.
But I think the best solution is create your query on your application from your view:

```
SELECT datetime(field) as field FROM view
```

***TIP 2***

You can try also with the SQLite Administrator and play with datetime functions before to check the format.

***TIP 3***

Be aware of your culture globalization also, you can find a problem if you change the culture. Try to your soft work with only one and display it as you want, not as the culture wants. In my country for eg, we use as common this format: dd/MM/yy and is a pain, like the dot on decimal numbers (we use a comma)

***TIP 4***

If you are working with a wizard-defined connection on some report or entity or something like, be sure to check your desired conversion format. For example I use the most common and non problematic way: ISO8601

[image: SQLite - Add Connection]

Comment: Thanks. But currently I found no way. I'm a database-viewer with no know about the database. the default datetime format is 8601. This is in my table when I `executeReader.GetString(3)` = **"7/4/1996 12:00:00 AM"**

with `executeReader.GetDateTime(3)` I get the FormatException

Comment: I mean what is the name of your field? In your code you put "SELECT * FROM tablename. Try to change this query to SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, datatime(field), field6etc FROM table". Even is a not great idea do a SELECT * in an app

Comment: by the way, the datetime that you specify is not iso compliant

Comment: I not resolved the problem completly because. But I have a little workaround while reading out all columns with its type for building the select-string. the problem is that I don't know anything about the database

Comment: Oh that's another problem not related to the question, but you can do a select * from the scheme table to know all that information, is like the system table.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I view the database in [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org), I see Unix epoch values, however no matter if I set the connection settings DateTimeFormat to UnixEpoch, C# always throws the FormatException. Please help!

Comment: Did you check your culture settings?

Answer (score 6):

Did you try with `SQLiteDataAdapter` like so..

```
SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(dbCommand);
da.Fill(dt);
```

Chances are it behaves the same but it doesn't hurt to try ;)

Answer (score 1):

[See this publication](http://www.mono-project.com/SQLite) about SQLite and DateTime storage, under the heading of Storing DateTimes.

Comment: thank you but this is no help for me. This is a further explanation of my situatuion. But I don't store any data I only want to read it out.

Comment: Do you need the DateTime column? Instead of doing `SELECT *`, you could limit the columns and just leave out the DateTime value? It sounds like a format problem with the data.